# Does a non-powered mixer have the same level of output regardless of number of inputs used?

Tags: mixer, line-level

Some of my band mates say that having too many mics/instruments plugged into a mixer has a chance of overpowering the output to the power amp.

I say that the mixer is line level output regardless of the number of inputs being used. Whether there is a single mic only or three mics and four instruments, the mixer will have the same level of output to the power amp.

I'm right, right?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some essential misunderstanding of gain staging here.

The output is the sum of the inputs, plus or minus the fader gains.

8 ins, 2 outs with all the faders pushed to the max will distort the outputs, for sure. You probably couldn't achieve the same amount of gain from a single input.

So… you just pull the faders back until everything stays in the green.